# Eigen c++ debugging using LLDB

Tags: c++, xcode, eigen, osx-mavericks, lldb

I am writing a algorithm using the Eigen library because I am dealing with large number of matrices and performing different operations on them. I am developing the code on Mac OS X Mavericks, and I was trying to debug my code using Xcode and also LLDB through the command line.
Every time I run

```
expr a.rows()
```

where a is a variable of type Eigen::MatrixXd, LLDB itself crashes with a segmentation fault.
Am i doing anything wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: A program should never crash, so it must be a bug. You should file a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes please do file a report at http://bugreporter.apple.com, with the crash log and if you can make available a small sample project that crashes that would be even better.  However, given that this is a complex C++ library you might be running into a known crash in the C++ demangler that shipped with Mavericks.  If the crashed thread is `free` asserting under a call to

```
lldb_private::Mangled::GetDemangledName()
```

and then this is that crash.  For more info, you can have a look at the Apple Developer Forums post:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/904311

Comment: That wasn't the case. I did file a bug report anyway.Thanks.